# Event to indicate download started and/or finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I'm using anchor to download a file, and I would like to handle the start and end event.
I tried this...
JS:

```
function downloadReport(){
    $('#eventmessage').css('display','block');
    var $a = $("<a>");
    $a.attr("href","../dataObject/reporte/get_report.php);
    $("body").append($a);
    $a.attr("download");
    $a[0].click();
    $a.remove();
    $('#eventmessage').css('display','none');
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id='btn_ttab1' class='btn-table bt-act' style="cursor: context-menu;" onclick="downloadReport">
Download EXCEL
</div>
<span id="eventmessage" style="display:none">Loading...</span>
```

The downloaded file is an Excel file of 40,000 rows, created using Spout (PHP Free Library) and can last more than 25 seconds. That's why I want to get the start and end event so I can show a "Loading" message using something like a span.

Comment: Why not use Fetch? With Fetch, before the Fetch set the loading. After fetch, unset loading. In catch, show failure message

Comment: That way you don't have to care about the events at all

Comment: There are no events

Comment: I was thinking maybe I could use an iframe, load the URL and use Jquery.load(), what do you guys think, I will get home and try it in a while.

Comment: Look this similar question, to get idea to solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download